# Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Buenos dias

Estoy tratando de sumar los valores de un gridview que selecciono a un texbox, cree lo siguiente ( ver codigo abajo) pero me devuelve este error " Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid. "

Codigo

Private Sub SumOpcion2()

```
    Dim total As Decimal = 0
    For Each row As GridViewRow In Gvcobranzas.Rows
        total += row.Cells(4).Text
    Next
    TxtMonto.Text = total


End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Qué valor tiene `row.Cells(4).Text`? además, en ese punto no estás convirtiendo el valor de `row.Cells(4).Text` en Double. **Antes de sumar, debes convertir ese string a un valor numérico como "double, o float"**.

Comment: El valor es tipo float en la base de datos.

Comment: Por favor date una vuelta en "[ask]" y edita tu pregunta acorde a la guía para poder ayudarte a resolver tus dudas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que el error te lo marca con una string vacía (`""`) puedes intentarlo con este código:

```
Dim total As Decimal = 0
For Each row As GridViewRow In Gvcobranzas.Rows
    Dim x As Decimal = 0
    If Decimal.TryParse(row.Cells(4).Text, x) Then
        total += x
Next
TxtMonto.Text = total
```

Haciendo uso de [`TryParse` (referencia)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx) haces el *intento* de convertir el texto en número (es necesario declarar la variable **antes** del `TryParse`) y si es exitosa la conversión, entonces haces la suma; si no es exitosa, el programa sigue.

Comment: Ya no me da el error, el texbos se igual a cero pero cuando selecciono mediante el checck box no suma.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para aclarar qué es lo que quieres, ya que en el alcance actual solo es para que no te de el error.

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar el método `Convert.ToDouble()` para convertir el valor de la celda a `Double`:

```
Dim total As Decimal = 0
For Each row As GridViewRow In Gvcobranzas.Rows
    total += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells(4).Text)
Next
TxtMonto.Text = total
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Ahora me sale " Input string was not in a correct format. "

Comment: Dónde te aparece eso, en el For Each o cuando sales del For Each?

Comment: en esta linea : total += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells(4).Text)

Comment: Puede que los decimales que le pasas vienen con un '.' en vez de ',', prueba de poner `Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells(4).Text.Replace('.',','))`.

Comment: No funciona, probe ponerlo double e interger y nada, creo que tendre que buscar otra forma de hacer la suma de los gridview que selccione

Comment: El problema que hay despues de revisar de nuevo es que no hay dato en la celda que estas intentando convertir, es decir, no tiene valor esa celda, te devuelve String.Empty, que es lo mismo que "", por lo tanto no vas a poder convertir eso a Double ni a Int, revisa como insertas los datos en la Grid y si siempre tiene valor esa celda en cuestión.